# R repeat function and store each iteration as object

Tags: r, function

I am new to R.

I'm trying to create time series matrices with different frequencies out of a sample. To be more specific I have a matrix of monthly prices from 1870 to 2014 from which I want to creat new matrices with increasing frequencies from 1 month to 120 months. For each price frequency I need R to store a seperate object which can then be used outside the function. The original sample has 1730 rows (price observations) and 8 columns (variables).

So far I have come up with this. The function prints all the matrices with seemingly correct frequencies, however I don't know how to save the matrices in individual objects.

```
asset_prices<-monthly historical prices

     prices.rep <- function(x)  {
        i <- 1
        repeat {
            prices<-x[seq(1, 1730,i),1:8]
            print(prices)
           i <- i+1
           if(i > 120)
            break
        }
    return(prices)
    }

    results.rep<-prices.rep(asset_prices)
    results.rep #only returns the last iteration of the function
```

Help is very much appreciated.
thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO. By the looks of it your function isn't returning anything.  Functions only assign locally (within the function) unless you specify global assignment with `<<-`.  But that's not recommended - better to return the object you want and call the function like `results = prices.rep(..)`  Please try and submit fully reproducible and minimalised examples in SO as it makes it much easier to help..

Comment: Hopefully the function is now more understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this:

```
prices.rep <- function(x)  {
    prices <- list()
    for(i in 1:12) {
        prices[[i]] <- x[seq(1, 1730, i), 1:8]
        #print(prices)
    }
    return(prices)
}
```

This will return a list of matrices (assuming your `x` argument is a matrix).

You can also write it more compactly using `lapply`:

```
prices.rep <- function(x)
    lapply(1:12, function(i) x[seq(1, 1730, i), 1:8] )
```

Comment: This is not a solution. It returns a single list and does not create a separate object as an output each iteration as requested.

Comment: That's because that's a bad idea.